# returning a user defined function name when using a decorator with a callable object

Tags: python, decorator, callable, function-object

Consider the following code fragment.

```
def print_timing(func):
    import time
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.time()
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time()
        print '%s took %0.3f s ~ %0.0f min and %0.1f sec' % (func.func_name, t2-t1, int(t2 - t1)/60, (t2-t1) % 60 )
        return res
    return wrapper

@print_timing                                                                      |
def foo():                                                                         |
    return 'foo' 

class name(object):
       def __init__(self, name):
              self.name = name
       @print_timing
       def __call__(self):
              return self.name

bar = name("bar")
print bar()
```

This returns:

```
__call__ took 0.000 s ~ 0 min and 0.0 sec
bar
```

The object `bar` behaves like a function called `bar`, but exposes the internal implementation detail of `__call__` when used with the decorator `print_timing`. Is there a way to change the `name` object (perhaps by passing a suitable argument to the `__init__` function) so it returns instead

```
 bar took 0.000 s ~ 0 min and 0.0 sec
```

? I want a solution that will let the `print_timing` decorator continue to work with ordinary functions. Running
`print foo()` gives

```
foo took 0.000 s ~ 0 min and 0.0 sec
foo
```

Comment: The "`name`" class (sic wrt capitalization) is not the correct approach to the problem and should not be used, nor should the decorator be special-cased. Unfortunately we cannot say the correct approach because we do not know what you are really trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you use the decorator only on methods, they'll be passed `self` as the first argument:

```
def print_timing(func):
    import time
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        t1 = time.time()
        res = func(*args, **kwargs)
        t2 = time.time()
        funcname = func.__name__
        # Special case; a "name" instance has a "name" attribute we want to use instead.
        if len(args) >= 1 and isinstance(args[0], name):
            funcname = args[0].name
        print '%s took %0.3f s ~ %0.0f min and %0.1f sec' % (funcname, t2-t1, int(t2 - t1)/60, (t2-t1) % 60 )
        return res
    return wrapper
```

**Updated**: The wrapper now uses `func.__name__` by default, but if you use this on a `name` class (as in your original question), it'll use the `name` attribute of the instance instead.

I've used an `isinstance` test to determine that a `name` attribute will be present, but you could use duck-typing instead (`if hasattr(args[0], 'name')`); the `name` variable is so generic however that you most likely will get unexpected results when used on arbitrary class methods.

Comment: @Martijn: Sorry, I'm not following your point. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Faheem `wrapper` is the wrapped function; it get's passed the same arguments as the original method would, including `self`. Just remember, `self` is only called `self` by convention, you could name it anything, as long as it is the **first** argument to the method. The wrapper thus gets `self` passed as the first argument (in `*args`) and you can access it just as well from the wrapper. And `self` is your instance of class `name`, which has an attribute `name` which is what you wanted to print to start with.

Comment: @Martijn: I can get an approach like this to work, but only for function objects. As I mentioned in an addition to the question, I want the `print_timing` decorator to work with regular functions too. And doing `self=args[0]` does not work with functions.

Comment: @Martijn: I attempted an approach based on your answer. See my posted answer.

Comment: @Martijn: With your new version, I see `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "call_new.py", line 49, in <module>
    print bar()
  File "call_new.py", line 9, in wrapper
    if len(args) >= 1 and isinstance(args[0], name):
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types` with my original class. In this case, name = `__call__`. I'm not sure exactly what you are shooting for here. What is wrong with 'hasattr' again? One could always using something else instead of 'name' as the magic attribute.

Comment: @Faheem: my code contained an error; the local variable `name` masked the class `name` so it was testing against that instead of the class. Renamed to `funcname` in my answer now. If you rename the `name` attribute of your `name` class to something a little less generic then `hasattr` should be fine too. :-)

Comment: @Martijn: Yes, `if len(args) >= 1 and hasattr(args[0], 'name'):` works. With your change, the new code works as well. But you are actually testing for a class called 'name'? That's very restrictive.

Comment: That's why I gave you the option to use duck-typing with `hasattr` instead. It's all about choices, but you have to be sure the `name` attribute is there on the first argument. Note that you can still screw this up by passing in a `name` instance to a normal function that has been decorated with your class (`def foo(oneargument)` then `foo(name('something'))` will use `something` as the name..

Answer (score 1):

No. The decorator happens when the *class* is built, and the `__init__()` call happens when the *instance* is built. You would need to have the decorator turn the function into a descriptor and have that descriptor get the name from the instance.

Comment: > Thanks for your reply. Can you sketch how such an approach would work, please?

Comment: The descriptor's [`__get__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) would bind the method, get the name from the object and assign it to the new bound method, then return the method.

Comment: After some fiddling, still not sure what you had in mind. Would your method work smoothly with both functions and function objects? Could you provide an illustrative example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `@print_timing` as a class decorator:

```
@print_timing
class name(object):
    ...
```

No changes are necessary; your wrapped object is now a function when it was supposed to be a class, but I infer from your question (and the fact it is a callable class) that it doesn't really matter (if it did, you could modify the decorator to make the returned wrapped object "prettier").

Comment: @ninjagecko: I'm not sure what you had in mind here, but using it as a class decorator just means that the class name is returned, in this case, `name`, so the output message is `name took 0.000 s ~ 0 min and 0.0 sec`.

Comment: @Fareem: why are you making this `Name` class? (sidenote: class names are usually uppercase by convention)

Comment: @ninjagecko: Not sure I understand your question, but if you mean, why a class rather then a function, it is because I have two very similar functions (a lot of common code), and I'm abstracting out some similar functionality as functions, and then passing it to the class __init__. So, one class in the place of two functions, essentially.

Comment: @Fareem: That is completely not the way you want to do it. You want to either have 1 function, or bring the "common code" outside of the function and have 2 functions. You don't need classes. Functions can call other functions. Functions can even modify variables outside of their definitions (as long as it's higher in scope) with the `nonlocal ...` keyword. There is also no reason to use `__call__`. Special-casing the decorator is also very poor form. The decorator is working just fine and should not be changed.

Comment: @ninjagecko: Thanks for your comments. I didn't think much about the possibility of staying with a function, so I'll review my code and see if it is really necessary to use a class. Yes, special-casing the decorator does seem like a complicated way to handle this, though I did learn some interesting stuff about python in the process, eg. descriptors.

Comment: @ninjagecko: However, in general there may be legitimate reasons for wanting to use this decorator on a class method, even if it is unnecessary in my case. So, this question is still a legitimate one, though I don't know if the methods discussed here are the best ones possible.